# Post dummy in multiple groups and time periods DiD estimation

Tags: panel-data, econometrics, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I have a question regarding [an answer of another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/223520/213421) posted here.

My dataset seems comparable and has different policy treatment timings for different firms. The answer outlines how to construct the $\text{Policy}_{it}$ dummy variable (where $\text{Treated}_{it}$ and $\text{Post}_{it}$ equal 1), for different treatment timings with a difference-in-differences estimator on a panel data set.

In his example table, firm 1 has $\text{Post}_{it}$ (an indicator for the post treatment period) dummy values, which are equal to 1 for time periods 3 and 4. For completeness, a copy of his sample:

$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\text{firm} & \text{time} & \text{treated} & \text{post} & \text{policy}  \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 4 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$

I am confused as how it could be possible to have a $\text{Post}$ dummy equalling 1 for a non treated firm (firm 1), as the dataset contains different treatment timings (or no treatment at all) for different firms (ie. it is on a country basis). IMO this implies $\text{Policy}$ is the same variable as $\text{Post}$. Does DiD with different treatment timings require that for all different treatment timings there is a non treated (control) group?

I am not that familiar with stats, so if the wrong question is asked, that could very well be possible. Any clarification would be great.

Comment: After doing some additional reading on the topic, I think either my data is just different or the example doesn't apply for location based multi time period policy treatment (ie there is no $\text{Post}$ dummy equalling 1 for non treated firms) and this shouldn't be a problem. The model won't need a $\text{Post}$ dummy and be similar to this model: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/111691/213421